# Why does print screen not work for full screen applications in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, screenshot

Whenever I'm gaming and I need to dump the screen I have to use third party applications, always and everywhere, because windows has decided that it should take a screenshot of my desktop instead of my actual screen. I hate this. Why is this so? Are there any hidden options to return the old behaviour?

Comment: Does this occur for every game? Do you use multiple monitors? If you use Steam, what happens if you use the Steam `F12` screenshot function instead?

Comment: No steam, and this happens in all directx (9 only? I don't have any DX11 programs) games. OpenGL games however seem to be working great with the print screen windows function.

Comment: So just to confirm you're looking in the right place? Using Windows Key + Print screen *should* save files to `C:\Users\(user-name)\Pictures\Screenshots`. Also: just one monitor? The other thing I found [online](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/27496-win-key-printscreen-broken.html) is disabling one of the settings in Taskbar->Properties->Navigation. If 'Always Show Start on my Main Display...' is enabled, try disabling it.

Comment: I use CTRL+V in paint to view the screenshot, I don't have any screenshots stored in my pictures folder. Unchecking all options in that tab and restarting the laptop does not solve the "issue".

Comment: I mean there are screenshot but in another folder, and they contain exactly the same data as the clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

Uncheck Disable fullscreen optimisation in the properties of your application.
Restart and u r done.

Comment: What applications support that and have that option?